# Prevent accessing videos, but allow them to be displayed on site?

Tags: iis, vps

I'm trying to display some videos on my VPS with IIS on my webpage but also to deny access for downloading them. I know there are some rules for apache, but I can't find a way for IIS and I've tried lots of things like URL rewrite, MIME types, Request filtering... How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this rule.
It will  block any video request with null REFERER header from your domain. You can modify the extension name based in {URL} condition pattern.

Of course, if you want to prevent request referred from other website, it is recommended to set CORS header.
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com

```
   <rule name="redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="(mpeg|mp4)" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example.com" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern=".+" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="AbortRequest" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much!! Could you explain what is the third "<add input..." for?

Comment: <add input means insert condition pattern. First input means the URL contain mpeg or mp4. The second input{HTTP_HOST} means the request must come from your domain.  HTTP_REFERER will be null if user access video file directly. So It can be used verify whether user is accessing the video directly or not.